# Return an integer from OnClickListener to outside the function (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android

So hey guys I want to return an integer to outside my OnClickListener function:

```
 hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int choice = 1;
        }
    });

if (choice == 1) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Sorry for this newbie question, but I've got no idea how to solve this... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making `choice` a member field of your activity:

```
int choice; // member field

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    . . .
    hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            choice = 1; // no "int" declaration
        }
    });
}

// later inside some method:
    if (choice == 1) {
        // do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
int choice = 0;

hello.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           choice = 1;
       }
   });

if (choice == 1) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClickListener` is an interface, which means you must implement `onClick` method which returns `void`. You can set `choice` to be a global member (define it before `onCreate`) and set its value in the `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

```
        int chocie = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}



hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int choice = 1;
           runTesting();
    }
});


 `       public void runTesting(){
```

`switch(choice){`

```
case 1:
```

// due stuff

```
break;
}
```

}

Comment: `int chocie = null;` isn't going to compile.

Comment: sry current rember how to initilize int varibals